# Optional Chaining in one step?

Tags: swift, xcode, option-type

Why does this work (Example 1):

```
if let numString:String = Model.selectedLocation?.zip{
        let callString:String = String(format:"tel:%@",numString)
        //more code here
    }
```

But not this (Example 2):

```
if let numString:String = String(format:"tel:%@",Model.selectedLocation?.zip){
        //more code here
    }
```

In the second example, Xcode throws an error and wants `zip` to be unwrapped like:
 `String(format:"tel:%@",(Model.selectedLocation?.zip)!)`
but if I do that the app will crash when `zip` is nil.

QUESTION: 
Is there a way to make the second example above work or is it not possible/correct?

Comment: Don't use `String(format:)` in this case. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly spoken Example 2 is neither optional binding nor optional chaining because `String(format...)` returns a non-optional `String` and the `format` parameter must be non-optional, too.

Example 1 is the correct and recommended syntax to handle the optionals.

Edit: I totally agree with Alexander's answer (except that `String(format:)` returns `String?`)

Comment: I think your comment is correct and there is no way to do it all in one line like I was hoping.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. Avoid redundant type annotations
2. Avoid `String(format:)` unless you need it. It's a method of `NSString` from the `Foundation` framework, which has several consequences:

   1. It requires `Foundation` to be imported.
   2. It implicitly bridges your `String` to `NSString`.
   3. It won't work in `Swift 3`, because bridging was made explicit.

The root issue here is that `String(format:)` returns `String?` (since the format string could be invalid). You can avoid this entirely by using Swift's string interpolation:

```
if let numString = Model.selectedLocation?.zip {
    let callString = "tel: \(numString)"
    //more code here
}
```

...or simple concatination:

```
if let numString = Model.selectedLocation?.zip {
    let callString = "tel: " + numString
    //more code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is useful info too!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

It is because in String(format: " ", ), the **arguments** must be not-nil, hence the **!**.

when using if-let check for optionals, statements must return optionals

```
// Assuming Model.selectionLocation.zip is of String type
if let numberString = Model.selectedLocation?.zip {

    let formattedString = String(format:"tel:%@", numberString)

}
```

or use **guard**

```
    guard let numberString = Model.selectedLocation?.zip else {
        return
    }
    let numberString = String(format:"tel:%@", numberString)
```

Comment: 1-) doesn't compile because String(format...) returns a non-optional.

Comment: have you checked it, @vadian? The answer is correct

Comment: @AlexanderTkachenko Yes, the error message is *initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'*

Comment: thanks for the replay. I tried example 1 but it throws an error  "binding must have Optional type, not String"

Comment: @vadian Sorry for that, I'll check once again